# With Git, how can I commit some changes in the working copy to a different branch?

Tags: git, branch, commit, partial

I'm working in a branch, and got a working copy with is really unclean. When looking through the changes to commit, I wanted a few oneliner fixes to be committed to the `master` branch.

In this case, using `git stash` is not really helping, because my working copy has lots of other changes which won't merge with master yet.

Is there a more efficient way to fix this situation? (e.g. making a commit, and moving it's parent?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the previous suggestions, this is the solution I've come up with:

**Solution 1 with cherry-pick**

Just commit the single change at the branch itself:

```
git add --patch <files>      # record every change to move to master
git commit
```

Move to master, and cherry-pick

```
git stash
git checkout master
git cherry-pick <commitid>
```

Back in the branch, it can be rebased.

```
git checkout <branch>
git rebase master
```

For every duplicate commit, you will be prompted to type:

```
git rebase --skip
```

The duplicate commits are filtered out of the patch-set in the branch, and the history is clean. The final `git merge` can still be fast-forward after-all.

**Solution 2, without having to commit in the branch first**

First extract everything to move to master:

```
git add --patch <files>      # record every change to move to master
```

Then switch to master to commit:

```
git stash --keep-index       # clear the working copy only
git checkout master -m       # merge the index.
git commit
```

And back in the branch, it can be directly rebased to the tip of master:

```
git checkout <branchname>
git rebase master            # move to branch start to the tip of master.
git stash apply              # restore working copy, auto merges the changes
```

**Solution 3, make a clone of the current master branch**

In case you don't mind having multiple working copies (I always did this with SVN actually), there is a third solution:

```
mkdir ../newrepos
cd ../newrepos
git init
git remote add origin /path/to/your/repository
git fetch master:remotes/origin/master  # fetch remote master to local remotes/origin/master
git checkout -t origin/master           # make new "master" branch, link to remote, checkout.

git commit
git push origin master                  # inject the change in the original repository.
```

The clone setup is done manually here because `git clone` always clones the currently active branch.

---

For more complex situations, there is always an extra safe guard with `git diff > to-master.patch` and `git apply to-master.patch`. This allows you more freedom to reset everything, and try over until you get things right.

In this situation, we're dealing with a one-line fix in a file which exists in both branches. This would not give any merge conflicts, and allows some shortcuts like `checkout -m`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`git add -i`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-add.html) to use the interactive mode. There you can specify, what to commit and what to skip.

This way you can commit your oneliners as seperate commits. By using [`git cherry-pick`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) you can merge them to your master, later.

Comment: Been testing out git cherry-pick, and this works pretty neat! At rebase, the duplicates will be filtered out again with git rebase --skip. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3):

Use `git add -i` to choose what you want to commit to this branch, then change to master and commit the rest.

With `add -i` you can choose which parts of which files you want to prepare for commit and then commit them, while leaving other parts of the same files out of the commit.

Comment: In my experience, `add -p` is what most people want when they're using `add -i`

Comment: I frequently use `git add --patch` for these cases, unfortunately I also want to keep some changes in the working copy, so I can't switch branches.

Answer (score 2):

`git add -p` will drop you directly into patch mode to follow the process @arkaitz-jimenez correctly recommends.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you want, but I would just check out the other branch (which doesn't lose uncommitted changes), and then selectively check in the changes you want to commit.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `git add -i` / `git add -p` you can also use interactive add mode of `git gui`
 (probably other git graphical interfaces, that are in clude commit tool, like e.g. QGit, have this feature)